# JSP file don't identify request

Tags: eclipse, jsp, request

my jsp file must be able to receive information via the url. I used the method request.getParameter(), but eclipse don't identify request and this is an error. 
When I run this is the error 
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable request
  location: class org.apache.jsp.stampa_jsp

Thak you

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*,java.text.*"
import="java.sql.*" 
 import= "javax.servlet.http.*" 
 import ="javax.servlet.*"%>
```

```
<%! 
private String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample;create=true";
private String user= "user"; 
private String pwd ="0000";
public String updateDb(String ur, String us, String p){
    int id=request.getParameter("id");
    //String id = request.getParameter("id");
    int numero= 10;
    String outp="";
    try{
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ur,us,p);
        Statement st= conn.createStatement();
        int esito = st.executeUpdate("UPDATE parametri" +" SET numero= "+numero+" WHERE id in ("+id+") ");
        if (esito==1)
        {

            outp=outp+"inserimento eseguito"+" " +"<td><button onclick=\"top.location.href = 'db.jsp"+"'\">Visualizza  DB aggiornato</button></td></tr>"+ "<br>";
            }
        else
            outp= "inserimento non eseguito";
        //rs.close();
        st.close();
        conn.close();
        }
    catch(SQLException e) {outp="Errore nell'accesso al DB";}
    return outp;
    }
%>
```

The error is request in the line 
int id=request.getParameter("id");

Answer (score 0):

The return type of `request.getParameter()` is **String**,why do you assign it to an **int** value?It will throw an Exception when you run it

You can try using **String** as you just wrote below it:

```
String id = request.getParameter("id");
```